# Alignment when using a long double in a structure

Tags: c, struct, padding, memory-alignment, long-double

I know in general, a struct instance will have the alignment of its widest scalar member. I declared a structure having a member of `long double` data type.

```
struct try
{
    char a;
    long double b;
};
struct try obj;
```

When i tried to check `sizeof(obj)` it is coming out as `16`. My compiler assumes `long double` as `12` bytes. So i am not able to understand how exactly padding is being done here and how alignment is happening in structure. I assumed that alignment will be done on basis of `long double` as it is the widest scalar member. So there should be a `11` byte padding for char and the size of structure variable should come out as `24` but output is `16`. So exactly what is happening here ?. I am working on a `64 bit` processor.

Comment: Are you mixing up size and alignment?

Comment: what exactly you mean by that ?

Comment: Apparently alignment is on `int` 32 size: one int for `a` is 4 bytes plus 12 for the long float makes 16.

Comment: A structure doesn't always have to be aligned to its size. For example, a `char[100]` has size 100 but alignment 1.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, the variable will start on an int boundary.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie GCC and clang both tell me `_Alignof(char[100])` is 1.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, so `char a[101], char b` would be contiguous?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes: https://godbolt.org/z/f7K3FA (Or in a struct: https://godbolt.org/z/NQw85b)

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @S.S.Anne: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#index-m96bit-long-double  With -m32, it's 12 bytes and with -m64 it's 16 (by default)

Comment: @s.s.anne GCC codeblocks

Comment: IIRC, MSVC makes long double the same as double, so there it's 8 bytes.

Comment: @Noshiii Run this program on your compiler and see what it prints: https://godbolt.org/z/NQqhPv

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I don't think it's guaranteed, but there's no need to pad and GCC doesn't. https://tio.run/##ZcixCsIwEADQ3a84KkICVewc8UfUIbnk7EFNJLk4WPrtsbiJ2@Ph/o7Ythxxqj7AqYj3gQ7jefNznP5qYrde4yjwsBzVK7HX8zOvQarbves1dj0kohIkkSqSK8qMo81gL8NxuJmvnVl6cFqbpbUP

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: https://tio.run/##Zc69DgIhEATg3qfYnDGBhLPQTo2Jz2Brw/HnJrAYAYszvrqI1@mV800xo3qnVF0iKV@0gUPKWnp0tL4eFz@qjZ0Zxhl5HJpVpAxBIrFHRM2ft3sDy7ozjmYHq7EIOH1XgqE85Qt1AlJrowXmIznQsQzecAHTnX/m@1etb2W9dKn2Ybv5AA (Note the -m32 flag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your compiler is creating 32-bit output even though you have a 64-bit processor. Anyway, you're assuming that things need to be aligned to a boundary identical to their size, which isn't true in general. In particular, in your case, `long double`s take up 12 bytes, but only need to be aligned to a 4-byte boundary. As such, after your single-byte `char`, the compiler inserts 3 bytes of padding to get to a 4-byte boundary, and then inserts your 12-byte `long double`. 1+3+12 is 16, so `struct try` is 16 bytes long.

Comment: I am following this article for padding and align. : http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/#_structure_alignment_and_padding . Whenever i use a datatype which is less than or equal to 8 bytes in size this rule is working properly(all structure elements are getting aligned to the widest scalar member). but you said that long double is needed to be aligned to 4 byte boundary only. what is reason behind this ? I have'nt read any such rule in the article above. Can you please explain more deeply how actually boundary alignments take place especially when data type is more than 8 byte of size.

Comment: That doesn't contradict what I wrote. There are two scalar members in your struct: `char`, with an alignment of 1, and `long double`, with an alignment of 4. The widest of 1 and 4 is 4, and your structure indeed has alignment 4.

Comment: but as i said `long double` is of 12 bytes in my compiler. That's what my whole question is about. Why you are using 4 bytes for alignment. There gotta be some logic behind that ? sorry if i am missing something ?

Comment: @Noshiii That's just what the i386 ABI says. In your compiler, see what `_Alignof(long double)` is. It'll be 4.

Comment: Yes it's 4. I got it. thanks a lot.  Just one last thing, Alignment of structure depends on `_alignof(type)` and not on `sizeof()` ? Am i right ??

Comment: Yes, you're right. Note, though, that it's either `alignof` (from `stdalign.h`) or `_Alignof` (the built-in). `_alignof` doesn't exist.

Comment: oh okay, my bad, might be a typo. Will remember in future. thanks a lot for help.