# Packing long double with int

Tags: c, memory-alignment, long-double

On gcc/clang, `long double` use 10 bytes but take 16 bytes. It'd be good if this struct is 16 bytes but it's actually 32 bytes, wasting half of bandwidth.

```
struct {
    long double x;
    int id;
};
```

I tried to `union` two values, but [since compiler assumes the whole 16 bytes used only by the `long double`, editing it sometimes modifies `int`.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EdG9o3fo9)

Any good solution to pack them finely?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61429577/alignment-when-using-a-long-double-in-a-structure?

Comment: @EldinurtheKolibri It explains why the struct is 32 bytes but doesn't provide a solution to make it 16

Comment: Yeah you're right. sorry :)

Comment: You could get to 20 bytes by not putting them in the same struct. If you have a big array so the memory usage is an issue, then you could split it into two arrays taking up 20/32 = 5/8 ths of the space. This way would be safe and portable.

Comment: Use  `__attribute__((packed))` to reduce it to 20 bytes.

Comment: What bandwidth are you worrying about? Don't use `struct`s to serialize and parse data to a different machine.

Comment: For what system do you code? AFAIK On ARM64, a `long double` uses 16 bytes, without padding.

Comment: Beware that packing the struct to 20 bytes will produce misaligned long doubles if you then make an array of them.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 obviously 10-byte long double is a feature of x87 and only available on x87 or Motorola 68k

Comment: @l4m2, "Any good solution to pack them finely?" --> No, not if you want portable code.  Alternative: re-organize code at a higher level.

Comment: The best solution isn't exactly rocket science: don't store the `long double` and `int` in the same struct, but in 2 different arrays. Use array indices to group them together.

Answer (score 1):

> On gcc/clang, `long double` use 10 bytes but take 16 bytes.

I think you mean that the storage size of `long double` is 16 bytes, of which only 10 are significant to its numeric value (so 6 are padding).

This would be primarily a property of the target ABI for which the compiler is building, not of the compilers themselves.

> It'd be good if this struct is 16 bytes but it's actually 32 bytes, wasting half of bandwidth.

Have you considered using `double` instead of `long double`?

In any case, the `union` is the only way that C provides for two or more live objects to have overlapping storage, where neither object comprises the other. That does not serve the purpose of storing two overlapping values *simultaneously*.  Suppose you knew that the first 10 bytes of a `long double` were the significant ones, and that the size of `int` is 4.  You might then imagine doing something like this:

```
union problemmatic {
    long double x;
    struct {
        char padding[12];
        int id;
    }
};
```

But

- it is not safe to assume that writing to member `x` writes only the 10 significant bytes, leaving the others alone, and
- it is not safe to assume that writing to `x` and then writing to `id` does not cause the stored value of `x` to be a trap representation

That is, writing to either member could invalidate the other.

Bottom line: if you want to use less storage then use smaller data types (i.e. `double` rather than `long double`).  If you're committed to the data types you're using now then their storage footprint is part of the package.

Comment: you can do a manual `memcpy` to copy only the 6 significant bytes to avoid the possibility that all the 16 bytes were written when the `long double` was accessed

Comment: Sure, @phuclv, provided that you know which bytes of the `long double` you need to preserve, and that you know a valid way to set the others, you can manually pack the significant bytes of a `long double` and of an `int` into 16 bytes of storage, and unpack them later.  But that's not at all analogous to the OP's `struct`. And depending on how these data are to be used, it may be even worse for memory, because every time you want to access the `long double`, you need at least a separate, 16-byte staging space for copying it in or out.

Answer (score -1):

```
union {
    long double x;
    struct {
        int reserved[3];
        int id;
    };
};
```

Comment: See the godbolt link, it sometimes fail

Comment: Dirty. It depends on how the compiler / architecture places the `long double` inside the 16 bytes. Also, you depend on `sizeof(int)*3>=10`, which may not be the case. Better use `unsigned char reserved[10]` or `uint8_t reserved[10]`. General recommendation: Don't do it.

Comment: Generally, it is undefined behaviour to read a value that was not the value written last. You cannot legally use both fields of a union separately.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Dirty is unavoidable we're assuming `long double` take 10 bytes

Comment: You can't do that: 1)padding is compiler dependent, 2)members ordering inside a struct is compiler dependent. In the best case the code isn't portable.

Comment: @Frankie_C The compiler is not allowed to change the order of the members. But the compiler may add different amount of padding (but it has to be the same on one system, otherwise some libraries would break).

Comment: @Gerhardh: Re “Generally, it is undefined behaviour to read a value that was not the value written last”: No, it is not. Per C 2018 6.5.2.3 3, the `.` and `->` operators provide the value of the named member, and the standard does not state a restriction that the member must be the last one written, and note 99 makes it clear this lack of a restriction is intentional and that the bytes will be reinterpreted as the new member type. Attempting to overlap members as OP desires will encounter problems due to the bytes not being set as they desired, but not due to undefined behavior from overlap.

Comment: @Frankie_C: Re “members ordering inside a struct is compiler dependent”: The members of a structure must be allocated in the order they are declared. There may be padding between them, but they cannot be reordered. Per C 2018 6.5.8 5, a pointer to a structure member must have a greater address than a pointer to another member of the same structure declared earlier in the structure.

Comment: The lack of explanation makes this a horrible answer. (Also, int[3] instead of char[12] is weird.)